# Objective-C : Table cell just returns last information of matching data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to insert data into the rows I've created, I will get all info in my Log but it only shows the last info in all of my rows. Could anyone suggest a way to avoid this error?

Please offer me some advice thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are never re-populating the cells, actually. You are creating the initial visible cells, and just reusing them with the same content.. please look below:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath
 *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TestCell";

    TestCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
    // HERE YOU ONLY WANT TO INSTANTIATE THE CELL
        NSArray *topObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TestCell" owner:nil options:nil];

        for (id currentObject in topObjects)
        {
            if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[TestCell class]])
            {
                cell = (TestCell *) currentObject;    
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // HERE YOU WOULD ACTUALLY POPULATE THE CELL WITH DATA
    NSArray *array = [server get_texts:10 offset:0 sort_by:0 search_for:@""];

    NSMutableString *s = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    for (testMetaData *m in array){
        [s appendFormat:@"%@ %@ \n", m.title,m.note];

        cell.title.text = m.title;

        NSLog(@" title %@ ", m.title);

    }

    return cell;
}
```

---

Some info about `UITableView`:

So, a properly setup tableView only allocates and uses a limited number of `UITableViewCell`s. After allocating, say 5 cells (this number is determined by "How many cells can you see at any given time?"), it will take an already created cell that has been scrolled out of the visible area, and gives it back to you in that method you are using, so you can re-populate it. So, `cell` variable will not be `nil` at that time, and your server code never gets called.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with your for loop.

```
NSMutableString *s = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
            for (testMetaData *m in array){
                [s appendFormat:@"%@ %@ \n", m.title,m.note];

                cell.title.text = m.title;

                NSLog(@" title %@ ", m.title);

            }
```

Your `cell.title.text = m.title`will get the last `m.title` info at the end of the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath
 *)indexPath
{
//Load Cell for reuse
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TestCell";
   TestCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   if (cell == nil) {
      cell =[ [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TestCell" owner:nil options:nil] lastObject];
   }
//appending text and config cell
       NSArray *array = [server get_texts:10 offset:0 sort_by:0 search_for:@""];
       NSString *t = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//Config cell - Not sure what you want. Maybe 10 different rows
        cell.title.text = t;
        return cell;

}
```

Comment: thanks for reply but it just load the whole titles in each rows

Comment: seem you don't understand how to populate data in tableview. Learn indexpath and datasource. I guess you wanna 10 rows ?

Comment: I modify it. Is that your need?